# zsh suggesting what packages to install

Tags: bash, zsh

I love using `zsh` but there is one feature that `bash` has that I miss. It is this one:

```
➜  ~  bash

dbugger@mercury:~$ man2html
The program 'man2html' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install man2html-base

dbugger@mercury:~$ exit
exit

➜  ~  man2html
zsh: command not found: man2html
```

When I type a command that is not install, but it can be easily installed, `bash`tells you so, but `zsh`no.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure the `command-not-found` package is installed (it should be by default). Then open up your `.zshrc` file in your favourite text editor and append this line at the bottom:

```
source /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

Then run

```
source .zshrc
```

in your terminal. Now when you try to run a program that isn't installed:

```
➜  ~  man2html
The program 'man2html' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install man2html-base
zsh: command not found: man2html
➜  ~
```

Comment: That worked! I guess that after a reboot, I wont need to run `source` again. Shame that last line: `zsh: command not found: man2html`. If it was not there, it would be perfect. But that is probably just a small detail. Thanks!

Comment: @Seth Does this command also suggest snaps like bash?

Comment: @Maxwells.c can't say that I know. It probably does.

Comment: @Maxwells.c and future readers, it does suggest snaps as well